# What did Cosima Wagner mean by coating music?

Tags: music

I am reading the diary of [Cosima Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosima_Wagner) (Piper, München, 1976) where she often writes: Die Noten überzogen. That means she has coated the music written by Richard Wagner. I cannot find an explanation what she used to coat the sheets. Today we would perhaps shrink wrap them in order to protect the sheets. But that cannot be meant in 1869. Any idea what she did?

There is no context. I read several times: Abends wieder Noten überzogen.

One example:

> 26ten Donnerstag
>   Sehr freundlicher Brief des Professor Nietzsche welcher uns einen Vortrag über Homer zuschickt. **Wiederum Kindertag mit *Partitur-Überziehung,*** R. instrumentierend. Nichts von außen Gott sei Dank, als einige Aufsätze von Judith Mendes über die Ausstellung über einen Brief G. Herwegh's, welcher R. deshalb frappiert, weil [er] in diesen Tagen daran gedacht hatte, diesem armen Verkommenen ein Lebenszeichen [zu] geben.
>   [src](https://books.google.com/books?id=gQnwBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=Partitur-%C3%9Cberziehung)

Comment: Does it really mean what you think it does? Can you give a short quote or two with a little more context?

Comment: There is no context. I read several times: Abends wieder Noten überzogen.

Comment: Even in this 'context' I fear that "coating" *might* not be the correct translation/concept here. Compare word usage [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=NgfJDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT154&lpg=PT154&dq=partitur+überziehen) In the above: is this R re-working the notation? Unless you can somehow prove that this is *the* right meaning, I guess GermanSE might be consulted first? (or waiting for a music expert/native German speaker here)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [German Language.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

*"Partitur-Überziehung"* is a now quirky and archaic expression in German.
 *"Überziehen"* and its variants refer to Cosima's habit of re-drawing or 'inking' Wagner's notations from pencil drafts to a final, clearer and more permanent representation.

---

Evidence and proof:

Comparing the instances of this phrase (and the apparent absence of net-searchable other writers using it in this way) it looks to me as if she means something other than coating, namely transcribing?

> 2ten März
>   Beim Frühstück sagt mir R., wenn irgend etwas zwischen uns vorfiele, so käme es uns daher, daß wir uns zu sehr liebten und zu sehr voneinander abhingen. Sein gutes Glück, nennt er mich! Er geht an Wotan's Weck-Lied der Wala, ich bei den Kindern, mein Leben besteht aus **Erziehen und Überziehen.**

*ziehen:* to draw, to bring in Form; here to educate and transcribe? Perhaps like *rüberziehen* to pull move something over?

> 8ten März
>   Richard kam heute nicht zu seinen Skizzen, weil er die Korrektur seines Aufsatzes über Devrient zu besorgen hatte; das gibt einen betrübten Tag. Vor- und nachmittags überziehe ich die Partitur-Blätter bei den Kindern. Eva beängstigt mich durch ihren Zorn.
>
> 18ten
>   Von den Kindern aber erfahre ich nichts und bitte daher R., einige Zeilen an Hans zu schreiben, nur damit dieser nicht gereizt sei, keine Antwort auf verschiedene Briefe zu erhalten. Viel gestickt und überzogen, auch viel im Garten; prachtvoller Frühlingstag; »Winterstürme wichen«!
>
> 22ten
>   Ich verteile den düstren Tag zwischen den Kindern, der Stickung und der Überziehung der Partitur. Des Nachts kamen mir wehmütige Gedanken über die Liebe; wenn der geschlechtliche Affekt nicht hineinspielt, ist sie wohl höherer Art.
>
> 23ten
>   Mit ihren Ketten, sagt R., seien sie eigentlich innerhalb der Gesellschaft, wer für sein Vergehen öffentlich büßt, ist in einem rechtlichen Zustande. - Abends Diktat. (Nachmittags überzogen).
>
> 24ten Februar
>   Gute Nacht, schöner, tiefer, seit langem nicht mehr gekannter Schlaf. - Gestern besprachen wir mit R., wie es uns zuweilen drängt, uns einem Menschen anzuvertrauen. Dann sagte er, er glaube, es würde sich noch günstig für uns fügen, wir müßten unsren Stern haben. Im übrigen müßte man wägen und sehen, welches Leiden man sich erwählte. R. schreibt an den König[21] (16 Seiten), **und ich überziehe zwei Seiten der Partitur, wie heilige Runen betrachte ich die Zeichen, die sich unter meiner Hand färben.** Nach Tisch phantasiert R. etwas.

__I [cover/coat or transcribe] two sides of the score, like holy runes I look at the signs that colour under my hand.

> 25ten Februar
>   Richard träumte, wir seien verheiratet, ich wandelte im weißen Atlasgewande (nach Terburg) in unsrem geräumigen wohlbehaglichen Hause und zeigte ihm Eva in einer Ecke. Mich betrifft dabei, daß ich nachts wieder Todesgedanken hatte. Doch bin ich heiter, **das weitere Überziehen der Partitur macht mir Freude - ihm so nachzufolgen!** -

__But I'm cheerful, I enjoy the further ['overdrawing' transcribing] of the score - following him like this!

The parallelism between educating and transcribing is much stronger than between educating and coating. The slow speed evident from this – applying a coating should be quite speedy –, the colour from the fresh ink on her hands, the time she had in reading the notation, (while he sometimes experiments with instruments besides her. The parallelism between dictation and transcribing being stringer than dictation and coating: all point into that direction:
This is not totally about language, which she seems to employ quite unusally, but amplifying her secretarial services for him: he jots down his ideas, she brings it into clean form on paper.

Quotes copied from [COSIMA WAGNER TAGEBÜCHER 1 1869-1872 (ARS FEMINA Online Frauenbibliothek)](https://arsfemina.de/buch/cosima-wagner-tageb%C3%BCcher-1-1869-1872)

This usage apparently fell out of use in the German language by now and perhaps was a bit archaic in her times already?

But it is documented in [Grimm's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch) Wörterbuch:

> ÜBERZIEHEN v
>   Fundstelle: Lfg. 5 (1932), Bd. XI,II (1936), Sp. 682, Z. 11
>   m) 
>   schriftzeichen u. ä. überziehen, nachziehen: mögen sie (anrede) wohl ... meine bleystiftcorrecturen, insofern sie solche billigen, mit tinte überziehen Göthe IV 39, 21 W.; III 10, 22;
>   es war, als stünden schon in blasser schrift die zeichen auf dem pergament und er dürfte sie nur mit geübter hand schwarz überziehen E. Th. A. Hoffmann s. w. 1, 213 Gr.;
>   Wilhelm hat ... correcturen angebracht, ich hoffe, dasz sich sein feines blei ... nicht verwischt, an einigen stellen habe ich es überzogen Jac. Grimm im briefw. zw. J. u. W. Grimm u. s. w. 1, 97.
>
> <sub>„überziehen“, in: Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm, Erstbearbeitung (1854–1960), digitalisierte Version im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/%C3%BCberziehen,</sub>

*_translation_* characters and the like, *überziehen/nachziehen*:
may you (address) well ... my pencil corrections, as far as you approve such, draw over in ink (Göthe IV 39, 21 W.; III 10, 22);
it was as if already in pale writing the signs were standing on the parchment and he was only allowed to ink them with practiced hand (E. Th. A. Hoffmann s. w. 1, 213 Gr.);
Wilhelm has ... affixed corrections appropriate, I hope that his fine lead ... not blurred, in some places I covered it (Jac. Grimm in the letterw. zw. J. u. W. Grimm u. s. w. 1, 97.)

**So it seems that she either copied/transcibed notations into clean hand or overdrew the first versions of pencil with permanent ink.**

Still possible, but not as plausible:

In light of Cosima's word usage (compare another author, using it [similarly](https://books.google.com/books?id=oIo5AAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA490)), especially the runes-quote, I conclude the above to be more plausible than the following, related, and indeed implying a coating, in a different word usage context:

> [Die Offizere zeichnen mit Bleistift, überziehen es mit Milch (wodurch das Verwischen vermieden wird),](https://books.google.com/books?id=qxNLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140) […]
>   <sub>Friedrich Carl Ferdinand von Müffling: "Marginalien zu den Grundsätzen der höheren Kriegskunst für die Generale der österreichischen Armee", Landes-Industrie-Compt., 1810.</sub>

*translation* The officers draw with a pencil, coat that with milk (in order to minimise smearing).

---

It is over-/re-drawing or fair drawing. Wagner did create and compose with a pencil and that was then finalised with drawing the surviving lines in ink:

> Am Gründonnerstag (29. März, noch während Liszts Anwesenheit) ward der erste Akt des ›Parsifal‹ in der Dichtung zum Abschluß gebracht; zunächst mit Bleistift geschrieben, zu späterem Überziehen mit der Feder. Am Charfreitag spielte Liszt abends zu großer Erschütterung der wenigen Zuhörenden – die ›Funérailles‹ und die ›Vogelpredigt‹, als Klänge aus einer anderen Welt.
>
> Nachmittags pflegte er die Bleistiftskizzen des Morgens eigenhändig mit Tinte zu überziehen.
>
> Wiederum schrieb er den ersten Entwurf mit dem Stift nieder, um ihn dann einige Wochen später mit Tinte zu überziehen; letzteres oft nachmittags bei Lampenlicht. Gelegentlich war er dann selbst für das früher Geschriebene nicht immer gut gestimmt; so hatte er die ursprüngliche Komposition des ›Auf, Kundry, auf!‹ mit einem darüber geschriebenen, wütenden ›Schlecht‹ durchstrichen, um es hinterher doch mit einer ganz geringen, für gut befundenen Veränderung, zu fixieren. Sehr befriedigte ihn die Eingebung jenes Violoncellmonologs bei Gurnemanz' Bemühung um Kundrys Wiederbelebung.

All three quotes from Carl Friedrich Glasenapp: "Das Leben Richard Wagners  in 6 Büchern", Breitkopf & Härtel: Leipzig, 1905. ([online](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20007751524))

Or in other words, Cosima is indeed talking about a coating: she covered the notes and characters drawn in pencil with ink!

> [image]
>   [image]
>
> [From the auction:](http://www.sothebys.com/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.75.html/2016/music-continental-books-manuscripts-l16406) Wagner, Richard
>   AUTOGRAPH MANUSCRIPT BY HANS VON BÜLOW, SIGNED, OF ACT III OF HIS VOCAL SCORE OF WAGNER'S OPERA TRISTAN UND ISOLDE
>   THE STICHVORLAGE FOR THE FIRST EDITION OF THE VOCAL SCORE, a working manuscript, with autograph title-page signed ("Tristan und Isolde von Richard Wagner Vollständiger Clavierauszug III Akt S.61-93 Schluß) Hans von Bülow"), notated for voices and piano in black ink on up to twelve staves per page, with many deletions, alterations, corrections and revisions throughout, pages 42-46 heavily reworked in ink and orange crayon with additional inserted pages ("Supplement"), additional music and revisions in the lower margins, marked by and for the printer in orange crayon (for pp.173-[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch)50 of the edition), including "Akt 3" at the head of the title page, DIVERGING IN PLACES FROM THE PRINTED SCORE
>   97 pages, folio (33 x 26.7cm), including title and additional pages inserted for pp.42-45, later cloth-backed wrappers, no place or date [by 1860], lacking the final page, title re-margined and repaired, last page reinforced, trimmed by the binder, browning to margins of page 1
>
> ONE OF THE MOST FAMOUS ARRANGEMENTS IN MUSIC HISTORY.
>   Wagner began the composition of Tristan und Isolde, one of the most seminal works of the nineteenth century, or indeed of any century, in August 1857, completing the entire score some two years later. The celebrated vocal score of the work, was prepared and completed by Hans von Bülow (1830-1894), Wagner's great acolyte and one of the finest pianists of his age, by Easter 1860. The staging of the work, however, was delayed for many years, due to the work's supposed intractability, finally receiving its première under the baton of Bülow in Munich, where he was Kapellmeister, on 10 June 1865.
>   Bulow's arrangement stands as a pinnacle among the many services he rendered Wagner, providing a brilliant rendering of the latter's complex orchestral score for the piano (too brilliant perhaps for the average pianist, who would have to wait until 1885 for a simplified score, prepared by Richard Kleinmichel). That today it is regarded as a monument of selfless devotion by one great musician for another is due to the retrospective glow cast on it by the extraordinary circumstances surrounding the later première, which threw the hapless Bülow into a real-life love triangle that mirrored the on-stage passions of Tristan, Isolde and the deceived King Marke. For from 1864 Wagner conducted an affair with Bülow's wife, Cosima, an affair that resulted in the birth of three children, Isolde, Eva and Siegfried, before Cosima eventually asked Bülow for a divorce and left him in 1869 for Wagner. Although Bülow was devastated and resigned his Munich position, he remained in the following years, however, famously loyal to Wagner as a musician. The two never again spoke with one another, however, and Bülow never visited Bayreuth.
>   The first edition of the vocal score (plate number 9942, priced at 10 Thalers) was published towards the end of 1860, the first edition of the score having appeared at the beginning of the year. Although Bülow indicates on the title-page that the manuscript contains only pages 61 to the end, it in fact contains the whole of the third act, except for the final page.

Apparently, even today's German speakers need another word for [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=4HeAPeLuKocC&pg=PA325&lpg=PA325) [practice](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nh2N8E9xR9wC&pg=RA1-PA364&lpg=RA1-PA364) now, describing the old word with *Über-zeichnug, nachzeichnen, nachziehen*:

> Richard Wagner ließ seine teilweise Hunderte von Seiten umfassenden Bleistift-Skizzen von seiner Ehefrau Cosima Wagner mit Tinte **nachziehen** (Martin Geck, Richard Wagner, Reinbek 2004, S. 89). Die dadurch verbesserte Lesbarkeit erhöht bei der nachfolgenden Ausarbeitung die kompositorische Arbeitsökonomie. Derartig autorisierte und im Idealfall lediglich textbewahrende Über-Schreibungen gehören zur Textgenese, beeinflussen diese aber nicht inhaltlich. Doch gibt es Fälle, in denen eine **Über-Schreibung** die Textgenese beeinflusst. Richard Wagner ließ seine ersten, mit Bleistift notierten Skizzen zum Tristan von Mathilde Wesendonk mit Tinte **überziehen**, was stellenweise aber zu Fehlern führte, die Wagner selbst in den Entwürfen nicht mehr richtig stellte. (Die letzten 13 Blätter des 3. Aktes sind nicht in dieser Weise mit Tinte **überzogen**. Vgl. hierzu [Robert Bailey, The Genesis of Tristan und Isolde and a Study of Wagner’s Sketches and Drafts for the First Act, Diss. Princeton 1969](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Genesis_of_Tristan_und_Isolde_and_a.html?id=DC5EAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), S. 70). ([src](https://beethovens-werkstatt.de/glossary/ueber-schreibung-2/))

Comment: This is really a detailled and impressive answer! Had I enough reputation i would upvote it. But I cannot believe that überziehen means transcribing = übertragen. I have never seen that word applied in that way. Well, Cosima had a French education. Maybe that she misused it. On the other hand, Franz Liszt's native language was German (although he preferred French) not Hungarian (which he learnt only late in his life). And her German is very good. But there is another counter-argument: Cosima often mentiones that Richard copies his music.

Comment: After reading again the paragraphs from Grimm's Wörterbuch I agree to your interpretation.

Comment: Perhaps related/similar to the English use of ‘gloss’ as an annotation on a manuscript?

Comment: @ LangLangC: I am convinced.

Comment: @user37237 Now, after reading the correspondence between Wagner and Liszt, I started to suspect that his constant complaints about having to ink his own drafts being such a drag, he really looked out more for a reliable secretary than anything else.This alone really colours her diaries in a new light for me.

Comment: I think you excellently show that this is about inking, I do not understand why you bring up the possibility of transcription.

Comment: @CarstenS The answer grew and evolved. Initially and for a few edits I suspected the process to be somewhat similar to calking,mimeography, hectography or spirit duplicator. I am still unsure whether the final answer would come across without doubts (if I were to remove the alternatives and just give the now authoritative result).

Comment: @LangLangC, I think the answer would be better without speculations which turned out to be wrong. I mean, once one knows what *überziehen* means here, one realises that the word actually fits perfectly. Any remaining doubts should be gone after the Grimm entry, and the box at the end confirms the practice in that context. The quote *die sich unter meiner Hand färben* is also very evocative.